# etiqueta audio html5 no reproduce de streaming en iOS

Tags: html5, ios, audio

Tengo una web que tiene la etiqueta audio si el origen del audio es un archivo mp3 funciona en iOS. Pero resulta que si el origen del audio es un streaming de audio iOS no reproduce nada. La version de iOS es 10.3.3.
Gracias

```
<audio controls="controls" id="linkAudio"> <source src="http://192.168.1.25:8080" preload="none"  type="audio/mpeg" >Dont Support</audio>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var audio = document.getElementById("linkAudio");  
    document.getElementById("linkAudio").addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.getElementById("linkAudio").play();
        });

  </script>
  <button class="btn" type="button" onclick="audio.play()" >play iOS</button>
```

Comment: funciona perfectamente en Windows y Android

Comment: El streaming lo genero con el vlc emitiendo mp3

Comment: Yo acabo de hacer la prueba y me funciona bien (con el vlc emitiendo el stream por HTTP también). De hecho en este caso ni siquiera el botón "Play iOS" sería necesario, pues al usar el atributo `controls` se muestra un elemento en la página que tiene su propio botón "play". Eso sí, tienes que darle un poco de tiempo a que se llene el buffer en iOS antes de que empiece a oirse nada.

Comment: Gracias por responder @abulafia en mi caso con el navegador safari de iOS 10.3.3 no se reproduce el stream en la barra pone cargando y cuando le doy al play no se escucha nada, espero 5 minutos y sigue sin escucharse, no se que puede ocurrir¿?

Comment: Si el vlc emite por http

Comment: Pues no tengo ni idea de qué puede estar pasando. El código HTML que he probado es exactamente el que has pegado (salvo la IP y puerto que he cambiado al de mi VLC). Así que la única diferencia podrá estar en la configuración de VLC, que en mi caso era VLC Version 3.0.1 Vetinari para OSX (10.14), emitiendo por HTTP un archivo mp3 con método de encapsulamiento "raw". Pero por otro lado dices que te funciona en Windows y Android, así que no sé... mi iOS es 12.1.1 pero no creo que eso influya.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta @abulafia yo estoy emitiendo desde windows con el vlc 3.0.4 Vetinari y no hay manera de que iOS lo reconozca, estoy emitiendo mp3 sueltos y listas de reproduccion de mp3 de vlc (.xspf) y iOS no lo reconoce no se si habrá alguna configuracion adicional en el vlc o en el html para que iOS lo reconozca  ¿?

Comment: Bueno, pues... acabo de probar también con VLC en windows. Y también me funciona. La versión de VLC que tengo yo es la 2.1.5 Rincewind, pero no creo que eso influya. La emisión la configuré vía Ctrl+S ("Emitir"), HTTP, Perfil Audio (mp3). Como no sea un asunto de que la IP de windows no es visible desde tu iOS, pero no entiendo cómo es que te funciona entonces desde otros dispositivos.

Comment: Pues debe ser un problema de iOS 10.3.3 porque no hay manera de reproducir el audio desde la pagina web, lo puedo reproducir con la app de vlc con el volcado de red pero desde la web nada :(